# Does @synchronized block a whole thread

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

Say you do

```
MyLock *lock = [[MyLock new] autorelease];
@synchronized(lock) {
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
//some very long process
}
```

In the main thread. Does that mean till //some very long process is done, the main thread is locked? If some other thread call

```
    //Update on the main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Do some updates
    });
```

That some updates will never be called? Am I correct?

Answer (score 6):

If the code in the first code snippet never finishes, the second one won't be called, regardless of the `@synchronized` statement. The thread is blocked by the code that you're executing. The `@synchronized` statement is to synchronize data access between *multiple* threads and to be useful, it requires that all participating threads actually use the statement. It will not "magically" lock access to the data structure, unless all participating threads "agree" on it.

You don't use `@synchronized` to ensure that only one method executes on a given (single) thread, that is the case anyhow.

To give you a concrete example of its use, let's say you have an `NSMutableArray` that you want to protect from getting modified from different threads at the same time (which could lead to data corruption). In that case, you could always access it in a `@synchronized` block with the same lock token.

Example:

```
//Thread 1:
@synchronized (myArray) {
    [myArray addObject:@"foo"];
}

//Thread 2:
@synchronized (myArray) {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

This will ensure that the blocks of code that are enclosed by the `@synchronized` will never execute simultaneously. When one thread enters the block, other threads wait until it finishes, but *only if* they also use the same `@synchronized` statement. If you forget to use it on one thread, it doesn't help at all if you used it on the other.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. I think you dont understand the concept of locking. You should read more about syncchronization for example here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

You have to synchronize using the same locking object (same instance!) in every case when you access the code, which you are trying to protect. You can store the locking object as property of a class.

In your case:

```
self.lock = [[MyLock new] autorelease]; //in init method initialize retain or strong lock property

...
@synchronized(self.lock) {
   NSLog(@"Hello World");
   //some very long process
}


//Update on the main thread
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   @synchronized(self.lock) {
      NSLog(@"Hello World");
      //some very long process
   }
});
```

If you can use as the locking object, the object which your are trying to protect.